# Swiper JS scrollbar - z-index not taking effect

Tags: javascript, css, swiper.js

I am trying to implement the scrollbar which should be on top of another layer but z-index fails to take effect even though it has absolute position and all the necessary parameters.

```
.swiper-scrollbar {width: 20%; min-width: 20%; max-width: 20%; margin-left: 40%; top: 10px;  box-sizing: border-box; display: block; position: absolute !important; z-index: 4 !important; }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/h9dr31ce/4/

Any ideas?